# How to fix this warning :In file included from Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.2

When I update Xcode to 9.2 version,
I  get this warning:

> 1. In file included from /Users/MarkWei/Desktop/Working/kd-app-ios/WangJingApp/Pods/FDStackView/FDStackView/FDStackView.m:23:

like this, many Third-party libraries got this warning, how can I fix?

Screenshot:

[image: warnings screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

i fix issue :setings target  `CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=NO`